# Most Accurate Way to Find Records Between A Date Range

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to determine what is the most accurate and most efficient way to find all records between a specific date range in SQL Server - in which the data is stored in a `DATETIME2(3)` format.

Here are the four queries I am testing:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
DECLARE @StartDate        DATE = '5/1/2017',
    @EndDate          DATE = '5/31/2017',
    @PrevDayStartDate DATE,
    @NextDayEndDate   DATE;

SET @PrevDayStartDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @StartDate);
SET @NextDayEndDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate);

SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Using Dates]
FROM dbo.ccis_11001
WHERE ldstat_date >= @StartDate AND ldstat_date <= @EndDate;

SELECT COUNT(*) AS [DATEADD]
FROM dbo.ccis_11001
WHERE ldstat_date > @PrevDayStartDate AND ldstat_date < @NextDayEndDate;

SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Mixture]
FROM dbo.ccis_11001
WHERE ldstat_date >= @StartDate AND ldstat_date < @NextDayEndDate;

SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Cast Date] 
FROM dbo.ccis_11001
WHERE CAST(ldstat_date AS DATE) >= @StartDate AND CAST(ldstat_date AS DATE) <= @EndDate;
```

Next are the statistics from the queries:

```
Table 'ccis_11001'. Scan count 9, logical reads 152039, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ccis_11001'. Scan count 9, logical reads 153963, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ccis_11001'. Scan count 9, logical reads 153896, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ccis_11001'. Scan count 1, logical reads 125678, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Perhaps I do not fully understand how to read these results, but I found it strange that the query which uses two CASTS in the WHERE clause utilizes fewer scans and logical reads than the other three queries.

However, the execution of the query with the CASTS costs more than the three without; with the first three having the same exact plan:

[image]

But the reason for my post is that the count for the query in which I subtract or add a day to the original date parameter does not match the two queries that follow.  I understand why the first query might return a different count based on not accounting for seconds in the `DATETIME2(3)` field, but why would the second query I listed return a different result than the third and fourth?

Results:

```
Using Dates   DATEADD   Mixture   Cast Date
14394305      14482319  14478923  14478923
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think your matter of cencern should be the datatypes.

1. DATE gives you precision upto day 2017-05-31
2. DATETIME2 gives you precision upto microseconds 2017-05-31 00:00:00.000
3. DATETIME gives you precision upto milliseconds 2017-05-31 00:00:00.0000000

since in all your comparisions, the boundary dates are of DATE datatype, but ldstat_date is of DATETIME2 datatype, the ldstat_date may have some values in 'hh/mm/ss.mmmmmm' portion. this may be causing you the difference in records read. please check it.